# support for Multi Window wicket 6.x

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

Hi i am using wicket and getting page expire when ever two pages are open and I am trying to submit in on after the other 
is there a way to support getPageSettings().setAutomaticMultiWindowSupport(true) in wicket 6.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to know how big your pages will get and how many sessions you've in parallel. I think your page size (serialized) is bigger than `maxSizePerSession` and because of that only last page is stored on disk.

you can tweak your `IPageStore` settings a bit (but this will increase your resource usage):

```
/**
 * Sets the maximum number of page instances which will be stored in the application scoped
 * second level cache for faster retrieval
 * 
 * @param inmemoryCacheSize
 *            the maximum number of page instances which will be held in the application scoped
 *            cache
 */
void setInmemoryCacheSize(int inmemoryCacheSize);

    /**
 * Sets the maximum size of the {@link File} where page instances per session are stored. After
 * reaching this size the {@link DiskDataStore} will start overriding the oldest pages at the
 * beginning of the file.
 * 
 * @param maxSizePerSession
 *            the maximum size of the file where page instances are stored per session. In
 *            bytes.
 */
void setMaxSizePerSession(Bytes maxSizePerSession);
```