# Multiple Tabs and Page Expiration in Wicket 6

Tags: wicket

This question appears to have been asked already, but the only answer given is entirely unhelpful. ref: [support for Multi Window wicket 6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488068/support-for-multi-window-wicket-6-x)

We have been running a Wicket 1.4 application internally successfully for years. Due to the need to advance the compiler target, and other reasons, it eventually became necessary to migrate to v6. In the process, multiwindow support appears to have been completely deprecated.  Previously, it worked flawlessly with setAutomaticMultiWindowSupport(true) in the Application, but the wicket developers have for some reason decided to remove this support.

The problem is that if one has two pages, Page X and Page Y, open in different tabs of the same browser( and hence same user session ), each of which has a Form component on them( let's call them FormX and FormY ), and the user submits first FormX (added to Page X, version 6), then FormY (added to Page Y, version 7), the form Y submission results in a Page Expired error.

In spite of the above-referenced answer, this behavior persists even after increasing both inmemoryCacheSize and maxSizePerSession to outrageous levels.

Wicket 6 also seems to sporadically trigger Page Expired errors on back button usage, but this issue is not nearly as problematic to our users as the multiwindow support.

The question is, with setAutomaticMultiWindowSupport() removed, is there any canonical workaround to get this functionality working again? Thanks.

Edit:

I'd also like to point out that this is not the only issue Wicket 6 is giving us post-migration; it's merely the most easily reproducible. We also experience Page Expired errors when users press the back button on certain pages. It's almost as if Wicket 6 only maintains a single page in the session, and once another page is rendered, the prior page is purged. It's unclear from goggling if Wicket offers any means of obtaining current session or page store status, so whether this purging is actually happening or not is purely hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

Wicket 6 still supports multiple browser windows.
Please create a quickstart showing the problem and attach it to a Jira issue.

Answer (score 0):

We are also having the same issue using Wicket 6.19.  Has anyone found a resolution to this?

Our application is for calling customers to make orders over the phone, so sometimes a second call comes in when dealing with the first, so two tabs are opened on the browser.

We have a specific error where we open a ModalWindow on one tab but not on the other.  The window has ajax-enabled checkboxes and OK/Cancel buttons that are also Ajaxified.  Clicking these controls for a while works but almost randomly it will fail with the "Behavior rejected interface invocation" error.  Clicking on anything in the dialog after that repeats the error.

It seems like the controls for the two page instances are being mixed together, and because the window is not displayed on one page (so the controls are not enabled or visible) this eventually causes the exception to fire.

Overriding canCallListenerInterface to return true is both messy and is masking the real problem - has anyone solved this in a better way?